# Embed an HTML5 music player into a Facebook post using an Iframe

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-graph-api, iframe

I'm searching for a way to embed an Iframe into a Facebook post on a user wall.

I know we can do this using a flash app and the open graph API but I have seen it done using an HTML Iframe on the wall of Soundcloud on Facebook (https://www.facebook.com/soundcloud?fref=ts).

When you link a page from soundcloud and then launch the player from the wall it opens an iframe containing the player.

I don't know if it's a feature developped only for Soundcloud or if any developper can do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this a feature developed by facebook.

You can't see any special meta tags associated to iframe in soundcloud page.

Comment: Yes I know, otherwise I would have just copied/pasted the whole thing... But it would have been too easier ^^

Comment: So, is it possible to embed music player for our site? Or just bandcamp has the rights to embed player on FB? I am 80% done but when we click on play button, fb does nothing.

Comment: @RaviDalal You can easily embed a flash player using the Facebook OpenGraph meta tags. Take a look at the HTML of any Youtube video, you will see a lot of meta tags related to the Facebook OpenGraph API. That's how when you share a Youtube link you can play it on Facebook. That's what I used to share my player.

Answer (score 3):

Soundcloud is a [Facebook Open Graph Music](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music) whitelisted partner. That's how they're doing this...